# Remove elements from array on click in js?

Tags: javascript, html, css, arrays

I have an interface [ref below image] **where whenever user clicked on close button Image needs to disappear from interface as well as from the array as images are stored in array** but currently it is disappeared from front-end interface not from the array.

**How will I delete element from interface and removed from array together** ?

[image]

```js
//a list of img urls needed to feed the list of pictures with some
const images = ['https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_5terre.jpg', 'https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_forest.jpg', 'https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_lights.jpg', 'https://www.w3schools.com/css/img_mountains.jpg'];

//inits the imageList with pictures coming from images constant
//..so when the document is ready,
$(document).ready(() => {
  //for each url picture in the images constant
  images.forEach((o, i) => {
    //append a picture to imageList having that url
    appendImageToList(o);
  });
});

//appends an image to the list (where image is a picture url)
function appendImageToList(image) {
  var img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = image;

  //the img will be enclosed in a container
  let container = $('<div>', {
    class: 'imgContainer'
  });
  container.append(img);

  //creates the close handle for this new picture and adds an event handler on its click event
  let closeHandle = $('<div>', {
    class: 'closeHandle'
  });
  //adds content x to the close handle
  closeHandle.append('<i class="fa-solid fa-circle-xmark"></i>');

  closeHandle.click(() => {
    //when the button is clicked, remove this image from the list
    removeOneImageFromList($(event.target).closest('.imgContainer'));
  });
  container.append(closeHandle);

  //adds the container inside the imageList
  $('#imageList').prepend(container);
}

//removes all images from the list
function removeAllImages() {
  $('#imageList .imgContainer').remove();
}

//removes a specific image from the list
function removeOneImageFromList(imgParentElement) {
  $(imgParentElement).remove();
}
```

```css
/* rule to style every single img container */

#imageList .imgContainer {
  position: relative;
  width: fit-content;
}


/* rule to style the close handle */

#imageList .closeHandle {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.1.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.slim.js"></script>
<button type="button" onclick="removeAllImages();">Remove all images</button>

<br><br>

<div id="imageList">
</div>
```

Comment: Get the url inside `removeOneImageFromList` then remove the URL from the array using filtering.

Comment: I did not get, any demo or snippet! much appreciated.

Comment: What is the issue? Getting the url or removing a string from an array of strings? (also, please do not use w3schools)

Comment: @ChrisG w3school is just for ref, I have arrays of images(as array stored) which I need to delete on click close button from array.

Comment: Why do you repeat the question? I know what you're trying to do, I'm trying to help you help yourself instead of simply handing out the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `removeOneImageFromList` to also use `Array.splice` to remove the element that matches the `src` of the image contained in the container that is being removed.  You should also modify `removeAllImages` to empty the list.

```
//removes all images from the list
function removeAllImages() {
  images = []
  $('#imageList .imgContainer').remove();
}

//removes a specific image from the list
function removeOneImageFromList(imgParentElement) {
  images.splice(images.indexOf($(imgParentElement).find('img').attr('src')), 1)
  $(imgParentElement).remove();
}
```